# Detection of freed memory usage (FPC -> heaptrc -> keepreleased)

Tags: debugging, freepascal

Free Pascal heaptrc keepreleased is described as "useful if you suspect that the same memory block is released twice" but is it possible to detect usage of previously freed memory (object method call of freed object) with it? If it is impossible - can it be detected with other tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should do that. The idea is the following:

an used allocation has a different .sig then $AAAAAAAA or $DEADBEEF. On freemem the sig is checked (see around line 593 in trunk) against sig $AAAAAAA IF useCRC is false.

The keepreleased prevents blocks from being reused, which would change the signature to something else then $AAAAAAAA. It will print something like:

Marked memory at $12345678 released

to the file descriptor ptext. The error standard files can be set and directed using various other variables. It looks fairly complicated, but that is probably to deal with consoleless GUI applications

Some other variables (like haltonerror) govern if the application is halted on such corruption

An alternate (but very slow) way is using valgrind (fpc option -gv), but I only have run valgrind on *nix, and as said it is extremely slow, so not for very heavy processing apps.